# mciSendString check if music is playing

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that uses the `mciSendString` function to play mp3 files. The function that starts playing music is this one:

```
void PlayMp3(std::string name)
{
    std::string command = "open " + name + " type mpegvideo";
    mciSendString(command.c_str(), NULL, 0, 0);
    command = "play " + name;
    mciSendString(command.c_str(), NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

How can I check at a given moment if a music file is being played? I want to create a function `Mp3IsPlaying()` that returns `true` if music is being played and `false` if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63094/Simple-MCI-Player

You would write something like this:

```cpp
void Mp3IsPlaying(std::string name)
{
    std::string command = "status " + name + " mode";
    char status[128] = {};
    mciSendString(command.c_str(), status, 128, 0);
    return (strcmp(status, "playing") == 0);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is in C# but I got the point. Thank you.

Comment: @DarkAtom I translated it to C++